# Ignore SOAP tags in XML file 

Tags: java, android, xml, soap, xmlpullparser

I have a XML file with some SOAP tags that I want to ignore.

I was parsing the XML file with pull-parser but it stop working since that SOAP tags came along.

The XML file looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <ns1:getAllUsersListResponse xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.business.ese.wiccore.myent.com/">
  <return xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><![CDATA[<User>
```

and inside the tag `<User>` come all the tags that I want to parse (and I know how with pull-parser) and then

```
</User>]]></return>
     <return xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><![CDATA[<User>
```

until

```
</User>]]></return>
  </ns1:getAllUsersListResponse>
</soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

The thing is, I know how to parse normal tags, but I don't want to parse this Soap tags, I want to IGNORE the SOAP tags! Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Technically speaking, in your example `<User>` *isn't* a tag - it's inside a CDATA section, so as far as XML is concerned it's just character data (which in this case just happens to itself be an XML document).

Comment: it makes sense... but is there any way that I could extract the data inside that section and parse it as tags?

Answer (score 1):

Not being overly familiar with pull-parsing (I'm typically a SAX guy), I'm not probably not the most authoritative source on such things, but here goes...

I believe most (if not all) Java pull parsers should expose CDATA sections using a specific CDATA node (I believe in StAX, for example, the relevant event type is `XMLStreamConstants.CDATA`). As such, you'll want to parse your document and pull out that CDATA section (inside the SOAP `<return>` element) and extract its contents.

The contents of that section are the document you are interested in, so then you'd want to in turn run a new pull-parse over the contents you just extracted.

I'm sorry I can't be more help. Hopefully there will be someone else out there that can flesh the details out a bit more for you.

**EDIT:** in response to comments, you can achieve this using SAX as follows (exception handling omitted for brevity):

```
import org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

class MyParsingApp extends DefaultHandler2 // see note 1
{
    private boolean inCdata, parsingSubDocument;
    private String subDocument;

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        InputStream stream = ... // see note 2

        XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(); // see note 3
        reader.setContentHandler (new MyParsingApp ( ));
        reader.parse (new InputSource(stream));

        parsingSubDocument = true;
        reader.parse (new InputSource(new StringReader(subDocument)));

        ...
    }

    public MyParsingApp ( )
    {
        inCdata = parsingSubDocument = false;
        subDocument = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void startCDATA() throws SAXException
    {
        inCdata = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void endCDATA() throws SAXException
    {
        inCdata = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {
        if (inCdata)
            subDocument += new String(ch, start, length); // see note 4
    }
}
```

Some important notes:

1. Normally you would use a separate class as your content handler, probably one for the "main" document (including SOAP elements), and one for your "target" document (in the CDATA section). I've not done so here just to keep it as short as possible.
2. I'm not sure what format your XML is in, but I'm assuming it's in an `InputStream` here. The [`InputSource`](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) class will happily use an `InputStream`, a `Reader` or a `String` specifying a filename to read from. Use whatever suits you best.
3. You will need to use a SAX2 reader to be able to handle CDATA content. Your default SAX reader may or may not be SAX2 compliant. As such, you may need to (for example) manually create an instance of a particular SAX2 parser. You can find a list of some SAX2 parsers [here](http://www.saxproject.org/links.html), if that's the case.
4. There are probably more efficient ways of doing this too (`StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` might be options). Again, I'm just doing it this way for simplicity.
5. I've not actually tested this code. Your mileage may vary.

If you've not used SAX before, it's probably also worth running through the [SAX Quickstart Guide](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html).

Comment: Thank you. Any idea on how to do it in SAX then?

Comment: Hi. I tried your example (but I've created in a different class and my main class calls it). Like this: the Main class calls MyParsingApp p = new MyParsingApp(); and then p.doTheMath(); where doTheMath is what you have in the main However, when doing reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(); a SAXException is thrown and the program ends. This has to do with the SAX2 parser, right?

Comment: @Rita: it most likely means whatever setup you're using has no default `XMLReader` class. The exception description should confirm that. If so, I'd recommend looking into one of those SAX2 implementations I linked to. For example, if you were to go down the road of using Ælfred2 (first option on the list), you'd do something like `reader = new gnu.xml.libxmlj.sax.GnomeXMLReader ( )` instead.